# jQuery Tipsy plugin -- manual trigger not working

Tags: jquery

I found one jQuery plugin (tipsy) to display tooltip below 
http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

In link above i could see that **manually triggered** tooltip is working as designed. I copied the page, and save it *locally*, as **tipsy.htm** (together with auto-generated **tipsy_files**). Again, is still working.

Once I copied tipsy.htm & tipsy_files to `/public` directory of my Rails app. All tipsy features are still working , but NOT for manually triggered tooltip.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: It is working fine in IE7 btw, above is observed at FireFox 3.6

Comment: Check the JavaScript console of FF for errors.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do it like that. Saving a webpage locally could alter the page and the files its links to.

1. Download the plugin.
2. Create your own page.
3. Include the [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) library in your page.
4. Then include the plugin js file.
5. Include the CSS file for the plugin or write your own.
6. Follow the instructions for [usage](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/#examples) and create your html and JS for the tooltips.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the latest version of tipsy 0.1.7 (from jquery plugin tipsy project) is not actually the latest copy (perhaps the developer forgot to update?) - without the trigger functionality.

The latest copy is actually on the website itself, which is http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js

Copy the js, css (remember to edit the image path), and tipsy.gif

Comment: I realised the latest code  is hosted at github (https://github.com/jaz303/tipsy/) rather than the old jquery project page (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tipsy)

Answer (score 0):

Check the JavaScript console of Firefox for errors. That should give you an idea why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you used live option too. **live** option does not work with **manual trigger**!